# C# Windows Service EntityFramework AddRange SaveChangesAsync Crash Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, windows-services, savechanges

I Work On Windows Service With C# Language
and Use EntityFrameWork
I Add List With AddRange
And Save By SaveChangesAsync();
When Run SaveChangesAsync program crashed and closed.
but use SaceChanges() Saved Without problem.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IUnitOfWork>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;

    }}
```

UOW:

```
  public async Task<int> SaveAllChangesAsync()
    {
        return await SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> AddThisRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        return ((DbSet<TEntity>)Set<TEntity>()).AddRange(entities);
    }
```

Use:

```
      private readonly IDbSet<WebUrl> _webUrls;
    private readonly List<WebUrl> _tempWebUrlsToInsert;

    public MalwareDetectingManager(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _webUrls = uow.Set<WebUrl>();}
```

create list:

```
 var newWebUrl = new WebUrl
        {
            Url = normalizedUrl,
            Status = UrlStatus.BadUrl,
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now,
            AddedVersion = _version,
            UpdatedVersion = _version
        };

        _tempWebUrlsToInsert.Add(newWebUrl);
```

save :

```
 _uow.AddThisRange(_tempWebUrlsToInsert);
            await _uow.SaveAllChangesAsync(); //Crash Program
```

Comment: "When Run SaveChangesAsync program crashed and closed" how? What's the exception being thrown?

Comment: Program  crashed without exception but in output window show Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: "Error" code 0 (0x0) means "ERROR_SUCCESS" as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) and means the operations was completed successfully, so the program didn't crash, just reached the end of it's lifetime and complete successfully

Comment: of course but nothing is saved  on database. and no record is added.